# Location in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Question, I create:

```
$location.path('products?pageNumber='+$scope.page);
console.log($location.search().pageNumber)
```

And result is in url:

http://localhost:3000/product/list#!/products%3FpageNumber=1
and console.log write undefined

Why url is different than set location.path()

Answer (score 0):

you are setting a query string and reading at the same time, which will not work.

Try to read the value after you route to products.

Comment: still undefined